# How to integrate with linearly 'switched' Dirac delta?

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

So in a physical problem, I am expected to solve integrals of the form

$$ \pmb{f}(\pmb{r}) = \int_V d^N \pmb{q} \int_0^1 d \lambda \; g(\pmb{q}) \delta(\pmb{r} - \lambda \pmb{q})  $$

In the paper that I'm looking at, they provide an examples of solved integrals (without any deeper discussion whatsoever)

$$\pmb{f}(\pmb{r}) = \int_V d^N \pmb{q} \int_0^1 d \lambda \; \left(- \frac{b}{\pi a^3} e^{-2 q /a}  \pmb{q} \right)  \delta(\pmb{r} - \lambda \pmb{q})  = \frac{-b \pmb{\hat{r}}}{4 \pi r^2 } \left( 1 + 2 \frac{r}{a} + 2 \frac{r^2}{a^2} \right) e^{-2 q/a} $$

Here, $\pmb{q}$ is to be taken as the 3D spherical coordinates with $q$ being the radial component (not called $r$ as to avoid confusion). I can handle the vector algebra and the integrations pretty well in general, so by no means I am asking for help with the integral itself, but the Dirac delta part I just can't wrap my head around.

I guess if I had an integral of the type $ \int dx \int_0^1 d \lambda \; g(x)\delta(x - \lambda y) $ then I could consider the integral to be a "sum" of Dirac delta contributions ranging from $x=0$ to $x=y$, so I might be tempted to write it as

$$ f(y) = \int dx \int_0^1 d \lambda \; g(x)\delta(x - \lambda y) = \int_0^y dx \; f(x),  $$

that is basically integrating against a "window function" as opposed to just a point delta.

However, in my specific example the variable being switched on is not an independent variable but the integration variable itself. In the simplified notation I guess it would be

$$ f(y) = \int dx \int_0^1 d \lambda \; g(x)\delta(y - \lambda x) $$

So I think my question should be: how do I solve an integral of this type?

Comment: $\delta$ is an even distribution, so $\delta(y-\lambda x) = \delta(\lambda x-y).$ Can you do it now?

Comment: Not sure: what would I do next? I've tried taking out the $\lambda$ of the delta, resulting in a term $r/\lambda$, but I can't do the integral still from 0 since it diverges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing $g$ this is as far as I come:
$$
\pmb{f}(\pmb{r}) 
= \int_V d^N \pmb{q} \int_0^1 d \lambda \; g(\pmb{q}) \delta(\pmb{r} - \lambda \pmb{q})
= \int_0^1 d \lambda \int_V d^N \pmb{q} \; g(\pmb{q}) \delta(\pmb{r} - \lambda \pmb{q})
= \{ \pmb{q}' = \lambda\pmb{q} \}
\\
= \int_0^1 d \lambda \int_V \lambda^{-N} d^N \pmb{q}' \; g(\lambda^{-1}\pmb{q}') \delta(\pmb{r} - \pmb{q}')
= \int_0^1 d \lambda \; \lambda^{-N} g(\lambda^{-1}\pmb{r})
.
$$

Comment: Would the fact that $\lambda$ needs to be integrated from $0$ to $1$ not be in conflict with having $\lambda^{-N}$ in the integrand? I've tried to apply this idea to the specific example I have, but the result seems to diverge... Or, should I rather say, does this integral transformation work if $0$ is included in the integral?

Comment: @LaBelleCroissant. It depends on how $g$ behaves at infinity.